# Can G-WAN servlets deploy ReactJS single-page-apps to browsers?

Tags: reactjs, g-wan

I'm developing several React SPAs and have not yet decided how the apps will be packaged/deployed/hosted.

Most of my experience is with back-end development, so I am not very familiar with methods for packaging and deploying SPAs. I have some other team members who are well versed in those processes in general; less so with React.

I have used G-WAN in the past to create RESTful APIs (works great!).

Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with ReactJS but at TWD (home of G-WAN) we have worked on a smaller project for the [Global-WAN](http://global-wan.com) console (a powerful application albeit with a minimal tab-based and form-based UI).

Our motivations were to transfer the UI in one single (tab-based) page, and only have data to travel after that point (either using arrays or JSON). Some G-WAN examples illustrate the AJAX and event-based techniques we have used.

G-WAN's low-latency did marvels in our case, achieving a much more responsive user interface to the point that end-users believed it was a local application.

Sometimes, re-ordering and re-formating data is key to achieve high database concurrency, just like the scalability demo at the [ORACLE OpenWorld 2012](http://www.gwan.ch/blog/20121001.html).

One point that I have to mention for the sake of fairness, after the testing stage our app was delivered and operated through Global-WAN's L2 P2P VPN (featuring proprietary compression) - which greatly enhanced scalability (and latency) as compared to HTTP or TLS.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Gil. That's the kind of thing I was hoping to hear. So are you suggesting the contact or loan example in csp?

Comment: I was rather thinking of ajax.c, quotes.c, stream123.c, etc. This was a very active discussion on the G-WAN forums that, unfortunately, have been deleted 3 consecutive times by the different firms that have been hosting it - once the number of users reached 5,000 persons.

Comment: I have the stream[1-4].c examples, but cannot find ajax.c or quotes.c in my csp folder. Maybe the comet.c example?

Comment: Yes, some examples ewre published on the G-WAN forum which has been taken down by its platform owner. Sorry for that. comet.c will help, sure.

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS by itself is a front-end technology, once you build a production package the code compiles to plain old .html and .js that you can serve from any web server. You will need to prepare URL rewrite rules though (in development ReactJS dev server does it for you)

Things get complicated when other technologies are involved, such as isomorphic rendering which require the app itself to run on serverside using NodeJS runtime.